# If using html table to represent a spreadsheet type table is that semantically a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

If using html table to represent a spreadsheet type table is that semantically a table ?

i.e is that a valid use or should I really be using a CSS Grid Layout

To put it another way I know html tables should only be used when representing  an actual table but Im unclear what is an *actual table* .Does a spreadsheet whereby you enter data meet the definition or it is restricted to a read only table of the type you might find in a book ?

**Followup Question**
Assuming it is semantically a table then for the best user experience if users are editing the table like a spreasheet is it best to implement as an html-table or to use CSS Grid Layout ?

Comment: HTML tables are for displaying tabular data and since that's exactly what you're doing, I'd say it's perfectly fine and semantically correct.

Comment: HTML5 allows for using tables as formatting also so...